# Inventory Validation quantity

Tags: c#, sql

I'm attempting to create an Inventory System for a Medical store using `sql` and `C#` and I have the below code in

```
    private void cmbProductID_SelectedIndexChanged_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = @"SELECT [ProductName],[Total_Product],[Pro_Instock] ,[ProductSold] FROM [vwSalesTracking] Where ProductId=@idd";
        cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", cmbProductID.Text);
        dt = db.SelectRecord(cmd);

        if (dt.Rows[0]["Pro_Instock"]==null)
        {
          grdtractsold1.Tag = dt.Rows[0]["Total_Product"];
        }
        else
        {
             grdtractsold1.Tag = dt.Rows[0]["Pro_Instock"];
        }


            grdtractsold1.DataSource = dt;
        }
    }
```

in the above code i am trying that when Pro_Instock" ==null then  do grdtractsold1.Tag = dt.Rows[0]["Total_Product"]
else 
do grdtractsold1.Tag = dt.Rows[0]["Pro_Instock"];
but the problem is that when there is nothing sold an i try to sale either less then Total Quantity for example(totla quanity is 100 and I want to sale 30 goods it will also show us error or either i try to sale more then Total Quanity it also show message so how should i make that if the sold quantity is less then Total Quantity it should show message otherwise it shouldn'nt)

```
    private void txtQty_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        int val1 = 0;
        int val2 = 0;
        if (grdtractsold1.Tag != null)
        {
            int.TryParse(grdtractsold1.Tag.ToString(), out val1);
            int.TryParse(txtQty.Text, out val2);
            if (val2 > val1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selling quantities are more than available quantities", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtQty.Text = "";
                //  txtTotalAmount.Text = "";
                //cmbProductID.Focus();
                //txtQty.Focus();
                return;
            }


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Product Quantity Not Found!", "Input Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            return;
        }

    }
```

Thank You

Comment: What is the error you get exactly?

Comment: If you debug your code, does the DataTable (dt) contain any rows at all?  Is your DataTable initialized?